# Show that the function $f : \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$ is continuous

Tags: analysis

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ be an irrational number. Show that the function $f : \mathbb Q \to\mathbb Q$ is continuous, where $f$ is given by $f(x) = x$ for $x < \alpha$ and $x + 1$ for $x > \alpha$.

I'm not sure how to go about this, I've been trying to use the fact that every rational number has a sequence of irrationals converging to it, but it doesn't seem to go anywhere. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of continuous?

Comment: A broad hint: continuity at a point $p$ essentially says that $f()$ takes a neighborhood of $p$ to a neighborhood of $f(p)$.  Can you show that your function $f()$ is in fact constant on _some_ neighborhood of any rational $q$?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $q$ is a rational number, then $q\ne\alpha$ so $|q-\alpha|/2>0$. So for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta = \min(\epsilon, |q-\alpha|/2)$ such that $f(x) = f(q) + (x-q)$ whenever $|x-q|<\delta$. So then $|f(x)-f(q)|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that limits and values of f coincide for every $x$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ (the definition of limit is the same as in the real case, but when you say things like $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$, it is assumed that only rational values of $x$ are considered.

Now, if $x_0<\alpha$, then $f(x_0)=x_0$. Now let's show that the limit is $x_0$ too.

If we choose $r=\tfrac{\alpha-x_0}2$ (which is positive for this case ),
then $0<|x-x_0|<r$ implies that $x<\alpha$ too, and so $f(x)=x$ for all $x$ in that neighborhood of $x_0$. Then $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)= \lim_{x \to x_0} x =x_0$.

The case $x_0>\alpha$ is proven analogously.